# Can a Method have Different Entry Points based on Argument

Tags: c#, .net, methods

I have a method, but the whole method doesn't need to run all the time.
I want only parts of the method to run sometimes.
In trying to follow DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle, how can I have different entry points for this method based on a passed argument?

```
public void SetDisplayCollection(string input)
{
    //SWITCH:
    //Input 1 entry Point
    ChosenSite = SiteCollection.Where(x => x.Guid == chosenConcept.SiteGuid && x.Name == chosenConcept.SiteName).FirstOrDefault();
    //Input 2 entry point
    BuildingDisplayCollection = new ObservableCollection<BuildingConcept>(BuildingCollection.Where(x => x.RelatingName == ChosenSite.Name).ToList());
    ChosenBuilding = BuildingDisplayCollection.Where(x => x.Guid == chosenConcept.BuildingGuid && x.Name == chosenConcept.BuildingName).FirstOrDefault();
    //Input 3 entry point
    BuildingStoreyDisplayCollection = new ObservableCollection<BuildingStoreyConcept>(BuildingStoreyCollection.Where(x => x.RelatingName == ChosenBuilding.Name).ToList());
    ChosenBuildingStorey = BuildingStoreyDisplayCollection.Where(x => x.Name == chosenConcept.BuildingStoreyName).FirstOrDefault();
    //default no entry
}
```

For clarity sake, there are 3 desired scenarios:

1. Run 100% of the code
2. Run last 2/3 of the code (skip beginning)
3. Run the last 1/3 of the code (skip 2/3)

Comment: `if` or `switch`. But it's probably better to split the method into three methods and then have them call each other.

Comment: `ChosenSite` is uninitialized when you start with input 2, how will you resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way would be to use `if` statements:

```
public void SetDisplayCollection(string input)
{
    if(input=="1")
    {
        ChosenSite = SiteCollection.Where(x => x.Guid == chosenConcept.SiteGuid && x.Name == chosenConcept.SiteName).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    if(input=="1" || input=="2")
    {
        BuildingDisplayCollection = new ObservableCollection<BuildingConcept>(BuildingCollection.Where(x => x.RelatingName == ChosenSite.Name).ToList());
        ChosenBuilding = BuildingDisplayCollection.Where(x => x.Guid == chosenConcept.BuildingGuid && x.Name == chosenConcept.BuildingName).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    if(input=="1" || input=="2" || input=="3")
    {
        BuildingStoreyDisplayCollection = new ObservableCollection<BuildingStoreyConcept>(BuildingStoreyCollection.Where(x => x.RelatingName == ChosenBuilding.Name).ToList());
        ChosenBuildingStorey = BuildingStoreyDisplayCollection.Where(x => x.Name == chosenConcept.BuildingStoreyName).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    //default no entry
}
```

Certainly you can rearrange the blocks to simplify the "if" logic, or separate the three blocks into separate functions and call them individually, or use more complicated patterns, but the first step is to get something that *works*, then make it *better* as time allows.

Answer (score 1):

Work backwards, and try to execute the last step first, unless the requirements aren't met (`ChosenBuilding` isn't defined yet). In that case, execute the second step first. Again, if the requirements of the second step (`ChosenSite` are not defined) then you need to run the first step.

This is called lazy evaluation, but the general idea is as follows:

```
public void SetDisplayCollection()
{
    if (ChosenBuilding == null)
    {
        if (ChosenSite == null)
        {
            // step #1
            ChosenSite = SiteCollection.Where(x => x.Guid == chosenConcept.SiteGuid && x.Name == chosenConcept.SiteName).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        // step #2
        BuildingDisplayCollection = new ObservableCollection<BuildingConcept>(BuildingCollection.Where(x => x.RelatingName == ChosenSite.Name).ToList());
        ChosenBuilding = BuildingDisplayCollection.Where(x => x.Guid == chosenConcept.BuildingGuid && x.Name == chosenConcept.BuildingName).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    // step #3
    BuildingStoreyDisplayCollection = new ObservableCollection<BuildingStoreyConcept>(BuildingStoreyCollection.Where(x => x.RelatingName == ChosenBuilding.Name).ToList());
    ChosenBuildingStorey = BuildingStoreyDisplayCollection.Where(x => x.Name == chosenConcept.BuildingStoreyName).FirstOrDefault();

}
```

Now can force the evaluation of steps #1 and steps #2 given an input.

Something like this

```
public void SetDisplayCollection(string input)
{
    if (ChosenBuilding == null || input == "1" || input == "2")
    {
        if (ChosenSite == null || input == "1")
        {
            // step #1
            ChosenSite = SiteCollection.Where(x => x.Guid == chosenConcept.SiteGuid && x.Name == chosenConcept.SiteName).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        // step #2
        BuildingDisplayCollection = new ObservableCollection<BuildingConcept>(BuildingCollection.Where(x => x.RelatingName == ChosenSite.Name).ToList());
        ChosenBuilding = BuildingDisplayCollection.Where(x => x.Guid == chosenConcept.BuildingGuid && x.Name == chosenConcept.BuildingName).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    // step #3
    BuildingStoreyDisplayCollection = new ObservableCollection<BuildingStoreyConcept>(BuildingStoreyCollection.Where(x => x.RelatingName == ChosenBuilding.Name).ToList());
    ChosenBuildingStorey = BuildingStoreyDisplayCollection.Where(x => x.Name == chosenConcept.BuildingStoreyName).FirstOrDefault();
}
```